# magento - category product select + groupdeals extension

Tags: php, mysql, sql, magento

I have groupdeals extension and i would like to show in category view all products from this category and all current running deals from chosen city.

In one category works well but in the rest i have en error LSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.groupdeal_status' in 'where clause'

When I copied query to workbench returns appropriate products.

```
   public function _getProductCollection()
    {
        if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) {
            $layer = $this->getLayer();
            if ($this->getShowRootCategory()) {
                $this->setCategoryId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId());
            }

            // if this is a product view page
            if (Mage::registry('product')) {
                // get collection of categories this product is associated with
                $categories = Mage::registry('product')->getCategoryCollection()
                    ->setPage(1, 1)
                    ->load();
                // if the product is associated with any category
                if ($categories->count()) {
                    // show products from this category
                    $this->setCategoryId(current($categories->getIterator()));
                }
            }

            $origCategory = null;
            if ($this->getCategoryId()) {
                $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($this->getCategoryId());
                if ($category->getId()) {
                    $origCategory = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
                    $layer->setCurrentCategory($category);
                    $this->addModelTags($category);
                }
            }

            $this->_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection();

            //check the actual selected city from groupdeal extension
            $crc = Mage::helper('groupdeals');

            $currentCity = $crc->getCity();
            if($currentCity == null){
                $currentCity = 'Madrid';
            }

            $this->_productCollection->getSelect()
                ->joinLeft( array('groupdeals'=>'groupdeals_crc'), 'cat_index.product_id = groupdeals.product_id') //join groupdeals
                ->where('groupdeals.city = ? OR groupdeals.city = "Universal" OR groupdeals.city IS NULL', $currentCity);
            $this->_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('groupdeal_status', Devinc_Groupdeals_Model_Source_Status::STATUS_RUNNING);

            $this->prepareSortableFieldsByCategory($layer->getCurrentCategory());

            if ($origCategory) {
                $layer->setCurrentCategory($origCategory);
            }
        }

        return $this->_productCollection;
    }
```

I'll be grateful for any help.

This is example query which is generated:

```
SELECT 1 AS `status`, `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`, `e`.`name`, `e`.`short_description`, `e`.`price`, `e`.`special_price`, `e`.`special_from_date`, `e`.`special_to_date`, `e`.`weight`, `e`.`manufacturer`, `e`.`manufacturer_value`, `e`.`small_image`, `e`.`thumbnail`, `e`.`news_from_date`, `e`.`news_to_date`, `e`.`url_key`, `e`.`required_options`, `e`.`image_label`, `e`.`small_image_label`, `e`.`thumbnail_label`, `e`.`msrp_enabled`, `e`.`msrp_display_actual_price_type`, `e`.`msrp`, `e`.`tax_class_id`, `e`.`price_type`, `e`.`weight_type`, `e`.`price_view`, `e`.`shipment_type`, `e`.`links_purchased_separately`, `e`.`links_exist`, `e`.`groupdeal_status`, `e`.`groupdeal_datetime_from`, `e`.`groupdeal_datetime_to`, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`, `groupdeals`.* FROM `catalog_product_flat_3` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=3 AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id = '3'
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `groupdeals_crc` AS `groupdeals` ON cat_index.product_id = groupdeals.product_id WHERE (groupdeals.city = 'Madrid' OR groupdeals.city = "Universal" OR groupdeals.city IS NULL) AND (e.groupdeal_status = '1')'
```

'groupdeal_status' is attribute of catalog_product_flat_3 table.

I've noticed that when id category is double-digit works well but when id is single-digit returns error.

Comment: is groupdeal_status  a product attribute?

Comment: I added query which is generated.